# How to display Angular 2 Components in Non SPA Application

Tags: angular, single-page-application

I want to display Angular 2 Components in CMS pages (i.e. Non SPA) Application

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: You need to provide more details about what you want.

Comment: With Angular2 each of your pages kinda becomes an SPA applications. After every page change the Angular2 application will be reinitialized. I'm pretty sure Angular2 is not a good fit for your use case.